# how to configure credentials at outlook.com connector in azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created outlook.com connector in an azure logic app using visual studio.
From the logic app designer, when i select outlook.com. It shows sign option, where i have signed in with emailid and password.
But, when i look at logic app.json file below values displayed under parameters. I dont see email and password.
I need these values to be configurable so that i can change the credentials on need basis.
How can we achieve this. appreciate if any one can help on this.

```
"outlook_1_Connection_Name": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "outlook"
},
"outlook_1_Connection_DisplayName": {
  "type": "string",
  "defaultValue": "Outlook.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the credentials from json file but you can directly change the connection by navigating to the outlook connector from your designer > Change Connection > Add new > Use Another account. Here are the screenshots for your reference -

[image]
[image]
[image]